# MongoDB Atlas connection doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku, discord.py, mongodb-atlas

I'm creating a discord.py bot for servers.I was looking for free VPS and I have found a Heroku. I learned how to use it and I hosted my other bot for few hours. Then I'v created another bot using MongoDB Atlas database. The problem is that when I want to use commands which have to use database it doesn't work and it sends an error. Other commands work

I'v made some research, but on some forums they say that It's not possible without giving details of your credit card and some say that it's possible, but doesn't say how.

This is the error which I got from heroku logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-25T19:08:37.808124+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
2019-07-25T19:08:37.808126+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2019-07-25T19:08:37.808132+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 728, in invoke
2019-07-25T19:08:37.808133+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2019-07-25T19:08:37.808134+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 88, in wrapped
2019-07-25T19:08:37.808136+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2019-07-25T19:08:37.808165+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you have found Heroku, personally I would use repl.it as it doesn't require any money, with great up time, excellent support. You can run the bot for a long time unlike Heroku.

If you don't like switching have you used `pymongo` in the requirements.txt?

Answer (score 2):

This problem might arise if you have only whitelisted your local IP. An easy workaround at the sacrifice of security is to whitelist any IP (0.0.0.0/0) in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Or you could use VPC peering.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a SSL certificate error. You can set your own `ssl_certfile` option while hosting the databse - you can find the documentation related to that [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html#client-certificates).

If that is not the case, I'd suggest looking at your server log files and checking out what the error is there.

Hope this helps!